# Find neighbours / inside query in OpenMesh

Tags: geometry, simulation, mesh, cgal, openmesh

I'm planning to use a mesh library, likely OpenMesh, to run simulations of surface mechanics for a convex topological surface. A crucial point is to have a good neighbour search, i.e. know which face/vertex is closest to a certain point in space. Alternatively, an efficient inside/outside query might do.

Is this implemented in OpenMesh ? Can you think of another library doing this ? It has to be C/C++, and be fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a look at CGAL, the Computational Geometry Algorithms Library.
The class [`Side_of_triangle_mesh`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/classCGAL_1_1Side__of__triangle__mesh.html) can perform inside/outside tests. It can do it for `CGAL::Polyhedron_3`, for `CGAL::Surface_mesh`, as well as for OpenMesh.

Comment: Thanks ! Can you use CGAL with a mesh from OpenMesh without crazy overhead ? Also, in term of performance, is it decent ?

Comment: There is no overhead, as the mesh is not converted. We use same design as the Boost Graph Library, that is there is a tiny API of free functions for navigating in a mesh. And a traits class to get a mapping of the vertex/edge/face types to a canonical name. And as the higher level algorithms in CGAL use the small API and the traits class (which we both wrote for OpenMesh),  the higher level algorithms operate on the native mesh.